# Activate an excel sheet using an excel UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to activate a spreadsheet using a pair of listboxes. lstWorkbooks stores the name of the workbook. lstSheets is a list of worksheets for the selected workbook in lstworksheets. My problem is selecting values from these list is producing random behaviour.

Please see my code below

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wbk As Workbook

Private Sub lstSheets_AfterUpdate()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(lstSheets.Value).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub lstWorkbooks_AfterUpdate()
    Me.lstSheets.Clear
        For Each wbk In xlApp.Workbooks
            If wbk.Name = Me.lstWorkbooks.Value Then
                Dim sh As Worksheet
                For Each sh In wbk.Worksheets
                    If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then Me.lstSheets.AddItem sh.Name
                Next sh
                Exit For
            End If
        Next wbk
    Windows(lstWorkbooks.Value).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    For Each wbk In xlApp.Workbooks
        If wbk.Name <> "Personal.xlsb" Then Me.lstWorkbooks.AddItem wbk.Name
    Next wbk
End Sub
```

Any help here so that it produces the desired behaviour is appreciated

Comment: You don't need `xlApp`.  As long as the code is in Excel it knows that the parent of `Workbooks` is the application.

Comment: Also - what kind of "random behaviour"?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook On clicking the a value in the list box, it, might make the form disappear, render all the controls unusable, or sometimes actually work as expected. Other times it would select the appropriate workbook, but the worksheet list box doesnt react to the the selection

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 Private Sub lstSheets_AfterUpdate()
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(lstSheets.Value).Activate
 End Sub
```

but lstsheets could list sheets from any open workbook. You can't assume the sheet is on the activeworkbook. You need to ensure the workbook is active first, because the user could have activated a different workbook between selecting the workbook and selecting the sheet.

But another point is why are you trying to activate a sheet anyway. VB code doesn't require it, and the user would surely find it easier to just activate a sheet with the mouse if they wanted to see one rather than use a form?

Comment: No, it's not listing sheets from all open workbooks.  Appears to be working fine for me - except `"Personal.xlsb"` is case sensitive so it's still showing `"PERSONAL.XLSB"`.

Comment: I've edited to make my point clearer - thanks for the correction

Comment: The reason I am doing this is to be able to select an open excel workbook to load data from into another workbook automatically. But I thought provide that part of the project was not necessary to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: But you don't need to select or activate a workbook or sheet to access its data through vba - just specify its name.